# multiple default routes with iproutes2

Tags: linux, routing, iproute2

I am very confused by the semantics of `ip rules` when it comes to the default route.

Sometimes, I can have multiple default routes using different gateways:

```
# ip route
default via 10.0.0.4 dev eth0  proto static  metric 1024 
10.0.0.0/16 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.129 
45.79.69.51 via 10.0.0.4 dev eth0 
169.254.0.0/16 dev rath  scope link  metric 1000 
192.168.12.0/24 dev rath  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.12.2 
# ip route replace default via 192.168.12.1
# ip route
default via 192.168.12.1 dev rath 
default via 10.0.0.4 dev eth0  proto static  metric 1024 
10.0.0.0/16 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.129 
45.79.69.51 via 10.0.0.4 dev eth0 
169.254.0.0/16 dev rath  scope link  metric 1000 
192.168.12.0/24 dev rath  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.12.2
```

At other times, I cannot:

```
# ip route del default via 10.0.0.4 dev eth0
# ip route
default via 192.168.12.1 dev rath 
10.0.0.0/16 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.129 
45.79.69.51 via 10.0.0.4 dev eth0 
169.254.0.0/16 dev rath  scope link  metric 1000 
192.168.12.0/24 dev rath  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.12.2 

# ip route add default via 10.0.0.4
RTNETLINK answers: File exists

# ip route
default via 192.168.12.1 dev rath 
10.0.0.0/16 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.129 
45.79.69.51 via 10.0.0.4 dev eth0 
169.254.0.0/16 dev rath  scope link  metric 1000 
192.168.12.0/24 dev rath  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.12.2
```

But if I delete the default route, it is changed instead (or, more likely, the other default rule becomes visible):

```
# ip route del default via 192.168.12.1
# ip route
default via 10.0.0.4 dev eth0  proto static  metric 1024 
10.0.0.0/16 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.129 
45.79.69.51 via 10.0.0.4 dev eth0 
169.254.0.0/16 dev rath  scope link  metric 1000 
192.168.12.0/24 dev rath  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.12.2
```

What is happening here? Why isn't `ip route replace default` changing the default route? Why isn't `ip route show` always showing all default routes?

Answer (score 4):

In your setup you have two different default routes (with and without metric).

You can have multiple route to same destination target with different metrics.
`ip route replace` adds route, if this route didn't exist, and replaces it otherwise. In your case you haven't had the default route without metric, and `ip route replace default via 192.168.12.1` has added the default route without metric.

One more time: the routes to same destination with metric and without metric are different routes!

```
+------------------+------------------------+------------------+
| Command          | route to               |route to same dst |
|                  | same dst exists        | doesn't exists   |
+------------------+------------------------+------------------+
| ip route add     |  error                 |  ok              |
| ip route change  |  ok                    |  error           |
| ip route replace |  ok                    |  ok              |
| ip route del     |  ok                    |  error           |
+------------------+------------------------+------------------+
```

Comment: Is this documented somewhere? It seems to raise a lot of additional questions (starting with which route is used for what packets).

Comment: Not accepting that answer yet, because I think it doesn't answer the last part of the question (why does the route with metric only appear after the one without was deleted?).

Comment: @Nikratio the only logical explanation is that the route was being added by a network manager on your system